# Optimizing two merge statements

Tags: oracle, plsql, merge, sql-update

I have two merge statements one of which uses subset of rows of other. Is there a way to optimize the solution. PFB two merge statements.

#### Statement 1

```
merge into tableA using (select a,b,c from tableB where x='1')
on (tableA.a = tableB.a and tableA.b= tableB.b) 
when matched update set tableA.c = tableB.c;
```

#### Statement 2

```
merge into tableA using (select a,b,c from tableB where x='1' and b='2') 
on (tableA.a = tableB.a) 
when matched update set tableA.c= tableB.c;
```

Thanks in advance !

### Edit

I guess I confused people with same column names. First statement updates all the required rows except one which has no matching row in tableB. So in second merged I update that row with another value from some hardcoded row in tableB .

Comment: The question doesn't make sense, for several reasons. If these are not your actual statements, you may want to post the real ones. Why they don't make sense: for example, for the first one, how many rows in tableB have `a = '1'`? If it's more than one, do they all have the same value for `c`? If not, **which** of the multiple `c` values will be assigned to the `tableA` row? Then: You are asking for `tableA.a = tableB.a` where you already required `tableB.a = 1` - so why not just say `tableA.a = 1`? No need for `a` in the join condition. Etc.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question to avoid confusions.

I guess I confused people with same column names. First statement updates all the required rows except one which has no matching row in tableB. So in second merged I update that row with another value from some hardcoded row in tableB

Answer (score 0):

You just use the first one, because all the rows in the second are in the first. If you ran the first one right now, there would be no need to run the second one

Comment: Considering what I wrote in my Comment to the OP, this answer reminds me the old joke: "... we can buy a plastic Christmas tree, which can be used either as an elf or a Christmas tree, since it resembles neither."

Comment: First statement does update all the records except few. So I need to update the same record with another matching row's values. Statements are updated - pls have a look